# What is meant by "glanced over my shoulder to the parking lot"...?

Tags: language-explanation

From the book: *The Coven: Elemental Magic*, page 1:

> I frowned and glanced over my shoulder to the parking lot drenched in fog.

What does "glanced over my shoulder to the parking lot" mean? Does it mean she glanced to the side? Or behind her? (The parking lot was behind her...)

Comment: According to Goodreads, _[The Coven: Elemental Magic](https://www.goodreads.com/series/234103-the-coven-elemental-magic)_ is a series, not an individual book. So which specific book are you quoting here?

Comment: This is more an English language comprehension question. I'd recommend https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You're probably overthinking the "over my shoulder" part here. If you take...

> glanced over my shoulder to the parking lot

... and remove the "over my shoulder" part, you're left with...

> glanced to the parking lot

... which means that she glanced *towards* or *in the direction of* the parking lot.

Putting the "over my shoulder" part back in doesn't change that. She is still glancing in the direction of the parking lot. So if you know for a fact that the parking lot was behind her, then it follows that she must have been glancing *behind* her in order to be glancing *in the direction of* the parking lot.